# Classic ASP Object

Tags: object, asp-classic

It is possible to create an "empty" Object and create Object properties on the fly in Classic ASP?

Take this JavaScript example:

```
var sample = new Object();
sample.prop = "Object property";
sample.prop2 = "Another property";
```

What is the Classic ASP equivalent?  Do I have to write a class with getters and setters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you need to create a class for that

have a look at

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c19317/Object-Oriented-ASP-Using-Classes-in-Classic-ASP.htm

Answer (score 0):

JScript is prototype oriented, so you don't need to create a class to add members to an instance. You can add new members to the new object instance on the fly:

```
var sample = {};
sample.prop = "Object property";
sample.prop2 = "Another property";
```